# Epiphany/chrome like statusbar with its own background

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, gnome

I am trying to add a `statusbar` with my `Gtk3`+`Python3` app. Currently its done as:

```
self.overlay = Gtk.Overlay()
self.overlay.add(scroll)
self.box = Gtk.Box()
self.box.pack_start(self.status, True, True, 0)
self.box.set_valign(Gtk.Align.END)
self.overlay.add_overlay(self.box)
```

[image: The text inside the red area is the status]

Which is, due to `overlay`, writes over the `scroll`.

I can add

```
   self.box.override_background_color(Gtk.StateType.NORMAL,
                                       Gdk.RGBA(.5,.5,.5,.5))
```

But this is giving persistent area near the bottom, as shown in the next pic:
[image: screenshot with box background]

What I am looking for is `epiphany`/`chrome` like behavior, that `statusbar`, with its own background will appear only when some text is pushed to the stack, and will disappear after some time, like this:

[image: screenshot from epiphany]

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: It sounds like you need to `hide()` the status bar when you don't want it there?

Comment: true..but no idea how to do that

Comment: `self.box.hide()`?